# Scala: conditional yield with matching and side-effects?

Tags: scala

What is the correct syntax for something like the following?

```
var foo = 0
someIterator.foreach{ x => x.property match {
  case "a" => foo += 1
  case "b" => yield "current foo" + foo
}}
```

I.e., I'm trying to iterate over someIterator. When it matches one thing, it should update a local variable via closure; when it encounters another, it should yield some derivation of the current state to the resulting iterator preserving the state for successive iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Option[String]`, `unlift` and `collect`.

- `unlift` takes a function that returns an option and turns it into a partial function.
- `collect` is like `map`, except it considers only the elements for which the partial function is defined.

The following example demonstrates the approach:

```
import Function.unlift

var foo = 0
someIterator.map(_.property).collect(unlift {
  case "a" => foo += 1; None
  case "b" => Some("current foo" + foo)
})
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/5cIt0j)</kbd>

Comment: isn't that simpler to do `someIterator.map(_.property).flatMap{...}` instead of very strange `collect(unlift{...})` ?

Comment: @dk14 I'm not sure whether that would still return an iterator, but if it does, sure.

Comment: i'm sure it does - http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/scala/collection/Iterator.html

Comment: even `scanLeft` + `flatten` still returns an iterator (as you may see it from my answer). Scala's iterators are pretty powerful :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have the final value of `foo` then you can use tail recursion and you won't have to use a mutable variable too.

```
@annotation.tailrec
def f(l: List[Char], foo: Int = 0):Int= {
    if (l == Nil) foo
    else {

      l.head match {
        case 'a' => f(l.tail, foo + 1)
        case 'b' => f(l.tail, foo)
      }
    }
  }
val l1 = List('a','b')

f(l1)

l1: List[Char] = List(a, b)
res0: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanLeft`'s acumulator instead of variable:

```
someIterator.scanLeft((0, None: Option[String])){
  case ((foo, _), "a") => (foo + 1, None) 
  case ((foo, _), "b") => (foo, Some(s"current foo $foo"))
}.map(_._2).flatten
```

Example:

```
val someIterator = List("a","a","a","a","b", "a", "a", "b").toIterator

scala> someIterator.scanLeft(...){...}.map(_._2).flatten
res16: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> res16.toList
res17: List[String] = List(current foo 4, current foo 6)
```

So you still have an iterator as a result